# How to pass string parameter from t4 template to another one

Tags: .net, templates, t4

```
string templateText = File.ReadAllText(Host.ResolvePath("D:/TemplateGeneration/SchemaGeneration/GenerateTableSchema.tt"));    
Engine engine = new Engine();   
string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(templateText, Host);   
string RootPath="D:/TemplateGeneration/TemplateGeneration/MainTemplate.tt";
```

I am using text template and want to pass varibale RootPath as a parameter to another template which got triggered by this template.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your string into the Host.Session.
Session is a Dictionary, you put in a pair of the name of the parameter and the parameter value. 
After that you specify a <#@ parameter ... #> in the template and use it by the name. Name must be the same.

Comment: Thanks alot,but I've been asked not to pass it in session.I have to pass it as a string

Comment: So, you need to prepare your second template to be ready to receive a string parameter. You have 'partial' class which a generated from *.tt. You can wrote a second part of the class and add a property for this parameter. Problem which I can see - you first need to pass RootPath into main template. Could be through session or using additional property.